# How to change the root folders for Android productFlavors

Tags: android-build, android-productflavors

Is it possible to change the default flavors root path?

From:

```
---src
-----main
-----flavor1
-----flavor2
-----flavor3
```

To:

```
---src
-----main
-----flavors
--------flavor1
--------flavor2
--------flavor3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And if you don't want to add a line into sourceSets every time you add a flavor you may use closure like this

```
productFlavors{
    flavor1 {}
    flavor2 {}

    all { flavor ->
        sourceSets[flavor.name].setRoot("src/flavors/${flavor.name}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by using `sourceSets`.

```
productFlavors {
    flavor2 {
    }
    flavor1 {
    }
}

sourceSets{

    flavor2 {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest-flavor2.xml'
        res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor2', 'res']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/java','src/commonFiles/java']
    }

    flavor1 {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/java','src/commonFiles/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor1','res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

True, this can achieved using `sourceSets` but the correct and much more simple solution is:

```
productFlavors{
    flavor1 {}
    flavor2 {}
}

sourceSets{
    flavor1.setRoot('src/flavors/flavor1')
    flavor2.setRoot('src/flavors/flavor2')
}
```